# PHP - How do I generate strings with control characters or binary data?

Tags: php, string, unit-testing

For testing purposes I need strings such as:

```
"test\x00string"
```

I would like to loop over the control characters (00-1F) and generate the strings automatically so I don't have to clutter my code with 31 lines like this but don't know how to realize that in php.

Also for testing malformed utf I might want to insert other byte sequences into strings.

Comment: Have you tried `chr()`?  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php

Comment: @Jack I tried searching for "php generate strings with control characters" and stuff like that.

Comment: @Jack I also look at the php documentation for strings

Comment: @JackManey I also tried searching SO because I thought someon must have asked this, and otherwise I will, since it is the kind of question you can search for hours on it, but someone can probably answer it in 2 seconds. That's worth taxing someone no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For certain characters there are [predefined escape sequences](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double), which can be used in double quotes:

```
$nullByte = "\0";
```

However, if you're gonna loop, your best bet would be [`chr()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php):

```
$string = '';

foreach (range( 0x00, 0x1F ) as $i)
{
    $string .= chr($i);
}
```

And as a one-liner:

```
$string = implode('', array_map('chr', range(0x00, 0x1F)));
```

Comment: The link to escape sequences it incorrect, as http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php is specifically for regex, not for general strings. I'm editing this answer to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$nullByte = chr(0);
```

You can just concatenate bytes to make a multibyte string.